# VS 2008 Bootstrapper. Download Some Prerequisites and Package Some Prerequisites?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, installation, bootstrapping

I have an install that uses the bootstrapper that requires a few different packages.  One is the .Net 3.5 installer, and the others are important but not as large.

I'd like the .Net 3.5 installer to be downloaded when needed, but I want the other packages to be included.  Is there a way to do this?

I want some to download from the vendors sites and other to be packaged with the installer. How do I do that?

Comment: Old question, I know, but did you happen to find out how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must check if you are allowed to re-bundle the 3rd party products in your installation. (Check term of use of their installations).

If it is allowed, you can bundle their installation and execute it after your installation (or before).

If it is forbidden, you should open inform the user on the prerequisites and direct him to the proper URL for downloading it.

Comment: That doesn't really address the question.  If I say to download the prerequisites from the vendors website, one will get downloaded, and the others do not.  If I package them all together, the package is 150 MB larger.

So, how can I use the VS2008 bootstrapper to download .NET3.5 and install the other packages?  Is it really an all or nothing?

Comment: Maybe ClickOnce will be a better solution. I usually bundle it all together.

Comment: Thanks. I'm bundling it together. Just seems like I'm missing something.  Maybe I should just make .Net 3.5 a launch condition.